# Augur, publicBuyCompleteSets reverts

Tags: solidity, augur

I'm building a contract function that purchases and distributes complete sets of AugurShares for a specific market. (Testing on Rinkeby).

Version of Augur-core (node_modules/augur) used: https://github.com/AugurProject/augur-core

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.20;

import "./../node_modules/augur/source/contracts/trading/CompleteSets.sol";
import "./../node_modules/augur/source/contracts/reporting/IMarket.sol";

contract BuyCompleteAugurSets {
  CompleteSets completeSetsInstance

  function BuyCompleteAugurSets(address _completeSetsAddress) 
  public
  {
    completeSetsInstance = CompleteSets(_completeSetsAddress);
  }

  function buyAugurShares (
    IMarket _market
  )
  public 
  payable
  {
    uint256 amount = 10 ** 14;
    completeSetsInstance.publicBuyCompleteSets.value(1 ether)(_market, amount);
  }
}
```

I call this function through Truffle:

```
    var res = await contract.buyAugurShares(MARKET_ADDRESS, {value: toWei("1", "ether")});
```

I double checked and the market is valid. I am able to purchase the complete sets for the given market through Augur.js but I should be able to also purchase these complete sets through a contract function aimed at the CompeleteSets.sol contract. Any clue what might be going wrong?

Failing transactions: https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x824a064503ba92d54c6e498c0bab6413854fbd6f

Comment: 1. Your question should include the implementation of `fillAugurOrders`. 2. What do you mean `do the same through the contracts`? (since your solidity code doesn't seem to share anything in common with your JS code).

Comment: That was a typo, I simplified the code a bit for the question.

Comment: And 3. Your link shows `invalid address`.

Comment: And 4. Your edit does not make the expression `do the same through the contracts` any clearer. What are you trying to do that works for you in one place but not in the other place? Please show a piece of code for each case.

Answer (score 1):

Got it to work thanks to @aaaaaaaaaaaaa from the Augur discord

code:

```
contract BuyCompleteSets {
  CompleteSets constant private completeSets = CompleteSets(0x48FCc9d538B9C86bA9D35b3eB0e7f64EE2B4664f);
  address constant private cash = 0x2Da4d465978981BD75BbaC4C9f3bdA10bE0B465c;
  address constant private augur = 0x990B2D2aF7e87cd015A607c3A95d7622c9bBeDe1;


  function BuyCompleteSets(
  ) 
  public 
  {
      ICash(cash).approve(augur, uint256(-1));
  }

  function BuyShares (
      IMarket _market
  )
  public 
  payable
  {
      uint256 amount = msg.value / _market.getNumTicks();
      completeSets.publicBuyCompleteSets.value(msg.value)(_market, amount);
  }
}
```